# Chain where all the stages aren't known ahead of time

Tags: python, celery, task-queue

My app spiders various websites, and uses Celery to do it in a nice, distributed way.

The spidering can be split into stages, kind of like a chain, except I don't know exactly what tasks are going to be in each stage ahead of time. For example, a lot of spiders run one task to get a list of results, then run another task for each result to get more information on the result. I'm going to call this new kind of thing an "unknown chain".

**My problem is how to implement the unknown chain.** I'd like to be able to use it wherever a chain can be used, such as waiting for it synchronously, running it with a callback, or (most importantly) putting it into a chord.

My current solution is to have the task for each stage return the signature for the next stage. I can then create one function that synchronously waits for the unknown chain to complete:

```
def run_unknown_chain_sync(unknown_chain):
    result = unknown_chain.delay().get()
    while isinstance(result, Signature):
        result = result.delay().get()
    return result
```

And another function + task that does it asynchronously with a callback:

```
def run_query_async(unknown_chain):
    unknown_chain_advance.delay(unknown_chain, callback)

@app.task
def unknown_chain_advance(unknown_chain, callback):
    if isinstance(unknown_chain, Signature):
        chain(unknown_chain, unknown_chain_advance(callback)).delay()
    else:
        callback.delay(result)
```

The main problem with this solution is that the unknown chain can't be used in a chord.

Other ideas I came up with:

- Do some kind of yucky messing around with Celery's innards and somehow create a new kind of task that represents an unknown chain. If it looks like a task, it should work like a task.

  It would intercept whatever is reporting the task as finished, and check if the task is actually done or just returning the next stage. If it's returning the next stage, it would "forget" to report the task as finished and start the next stage, and chain something onto that which repeats the process.

  Not a very good idea because it will break when I update Celery. Also, I haven't looked too close at the Celery codebase, but I suspect this might be impossible.
- Create a new kind of primitive, kind of like `chain`, but called `unknown_chain`. I doubt this can be done because from my reading of the celery code, Celery is not designed to allow you to make new kinds of signatures like this.
- Invent my own way of chording unknown chains, like I invented my own way of running them with a callback. The question is, how the hell would you do that?